# Set up a single file for 24, 29 and 60 fps?

Tags: rendering, timeline

What's the right approach to setting up a single scene to be rendered at two or more frame rates? Ideally, I'd like to set up a single file once, and render out at 24, 29 and 60 fps... but I am not sure conceptually if I should remap time in the single file or create unique scene .blend files for each frame rate.

The skins will tolerate the highest resolution of 4K... so this is not an issue of visual resolution. Mostly I would like to have very similar visual sense of motion at the three rates... but is this asking too much?

Comment: You could make different scenes with linked data but different framerates within the same file.

Comment: Yes... and I do this for static assets... but (and here I am probably missing something) any animations I bring in with the linked file's assets are frame based... and are interpreted at the slower/higher fps?  And if I have missed something obvious.... oops.  It would be cool if I could make a tail wag 2 seconds long in a linked 'source' file, irrespective of fps in scene... and know that it would be interpretted as 2 seconds in all cases... but if that is possible I do not know how...

Comment: Animation time works with frames. If your change your framerate then change the **time remapping** value as well. map 24 frames to 29, or 24 to 60 depending on your needs.